# Break Beam Sensor with Node/Johnny 5

Tags: node.js, iot, johnny-five

I need to count (and estimate length) of boxes on a conveyor belt.  I was looking at the wireless solutions at Monnit.com but they only record down to the nearest second, I need to record into miliseconds to estimate the box length.  I'm familiar with Node and have been looking at Johnny 5.  Is there support for something like this with Johnny 5 and the Arduino Raspberry Pi stack?  If so, any suggestions on hardware/API to get me started would be great, I'm completely new to the hardware/electronics side.

Comment: If that's all you are doing you should be able to do this in nodered on Pi - or at least prototype it. On Pi, NR includes GPIO nodes so you can trigger on edges - will be a doddle to time them. Use a photoreflective sensor maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it working following this example: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/laser-trip-wire.md